# SQL Developer 4. How to compare package code in DB and local repository?

Tags: sql, svn, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can't find proper way to work with Subversion in sql developer. For know I find out the how to change code on DB executiong code from local repository, and no way to add some package from DB directly to repository (Only save as and manualy add to repository folder -> then "add"). And also is there some way to force developer compare current code on DB and  local repository. Avoid situation where code is overwritten. I try find this information for 4 days, for know I have a pot of beans, and no 100% right solution.

Comment: Sorry, but your post doesn't make much sense to me - it seems you have a couple of unrelated questions. Could you please post separate questions on SO for these and try to be more specific about what *exactly* you are trying to achieve and what your *exact* problem is?

Comment: Sorry. Can't find some tips how should I properly add DB code/sripts to local repository. For now I just make on each file save as, and then manualy add it to local repository.

Comment: I don't find build in way to synchronize SVN with DB code. But I find this program : http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbcode-svn-sync/ It's open source and will be good for non commecial use.          For know I find Red Gate SoCO for Oracle DB : http://allthingsoracle.com/put-your-oracle-database-in-source-control/ in my opinion it's best way to solve my problem, but it's not free(